# Loading an Image in Sapper/Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I am running a sapper simple code for a blog.
To load an image I use

```
<script>
import cactus from 'images/cactus.jpg';
  import PostList from '@/components/PostList.svelte'
  import {posts} from '@/posts'

</script>
```

The problem is that the image never loads from /static/images but only if is inside /src/node_modules/images

This causes all sort of problems with deployment. It is not a problem to do an export locally but a remote deploy will fail as the /src/node_modules/images  is probably in git ignore.

How can I load the images as it should be from /static/images ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your images in your `./static` folder and for example, you want to use them on your page

`<img src="./logo-512.png" alt="" />`

`logo-512.png` comes default with your sapper template (try doing this)

if you organize your images inside `./static/images/` then do this

`<img src="./static/images/image.jpg" alt="" />` this will work.

Comment: thanks a lot!! somehow I am sure that I saw in their example and docs that there is an import ... from ... and then the image in src as {variable}..but your method works too!